# How to run cronjob in docker, and how to see the result?

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, supervisord

currently, I try to run a cronjob in my container Docker, but I see no result.
My Dockerfile look like that:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu

# Upgrade system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y --no-install-recommends

# INSTALL GIT
RUN apt-get install -y git-core

# INSTALL mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client

#INSTALL CRON
RUN apt-get install cron

# INSTALL NANO
RUN apt-get install -y nano

# INSTALL SUPERVISOR
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

ADD /supervisor/supervisor_watch_.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/watch_.conf

# Add these lines to your own Dockerfile
ADD /script/crontab /etc/crontab
ADD /script/start-cron.sh /usr/bin/start-cron.sh
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

#ADD scrapyTor scrapy
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

my `supervisor_watch_.conf` look like that:

```
[program:cron]
command=cron -f -L 15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=0
stderr_logfile=/tmp/start_spider.err.log

[program:tor]
command=/usr/bin/tor
#command=/tmp/mytor.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/start_spider.out.log
```

and my `crontab`, it's just that:

```
* * * * * root echo "toto" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

After have build my image ( `docker build -t toto`) and run my container (`docker run -d toto`) , and when I want see to the result inside my container with this command (`docker exec -it ID`) , I see anything in /var/log/cron.log ....

How, I can fix this problem ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot comment but are you sure about : * * * * * root echo "toto" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1 do you tried without the "root" ? : * * * * * echo "toto" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1 I have a similar problem, let us know if you find something.